# Array state for combo box

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi im not sure why its only taking the last part of the array

I want to be able to take the entire array and use it as an option for the combo box

here is what i have so far

```
Object.keys(data).map((datas) => {
    let array = [];
    array.push(data[datas].info.bizName);
    console.log(array)
    this.setState({ value: array })
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Alexander! It's not quite clear what issue you are having. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is:
`let newData = Object.keys(data).map((datas) => {
 return data[datas].info.bizName;
})
this.setState({ value: newData});
`